# Different actions based on SELECT result

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

There are 3 tables (First, Second and Third). I need to check condition in table First and then make an action in Second or Third depend on the result. As it is a huge dataset I prefer to have it in one query instead scripting with PHP or so row by row.

The pseudocode could look like follows:

```
SELECT status FROM First WHERE userid=.... ;
IF 'status' = 2 THEN INSERT INTO Second (...)
ELSE INSERT INTO Third (...);
```

It can be converted to the form:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS cnt FROM First WHERE status=2 AND userid=.... ;
IF @cnt>0 INSERT INTO Second (...)
ELSE INSERT INTO Third (...);
```

The problem is that MySQL seems to not see the value of @cnt nor there is IF...ELSE... statement in MySQL for queries as far as I know (I may be wrong).

Comment: Use `SELECT ... INTO @variable ...` or `SET @variable = (SELECT ...)`

Comment: `IF` requires `THEN`.

Comment: *THEN INSERT INTO Second (...) ELSE INSERT INTO Third (...)* What is the amount of rows to be inserted? One or multiple?

Comment: ```IF 'status' = 2 THEN ..``` - you compare string literal (not column value!!!) with number literal, so this condition will produce FALSE always.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 2 queries:

```
INSERT INTO Second ( {columns to be inserted into} )
SELECT {values to be inserted}
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT status 
    FROM First 
    WHERE userid=.... 
      AND status = 2
    );
INSERT INTO Third ( {columns to be inserted into} )
SELECT {values to be inserted}
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT status 
    FROM First 
    WHERE userid=.... 
      AND status = 2
    );
```

Or use stored procedure.